# Pass JS params to controller when using button_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, erb

Maybe there is no way to achieve this without a form but I'm wondering. I'm calling a download_pdf method from a concern by pressing a button in the admin part of my app. Here is working code:

```
<%= button_to t('.download_pdf', :default => "Download PDF BTC Statement"), download_pdf_admin_user_path(@user), 
                                 :action  => :download_pdf, 
                                 :class   => "btn btn-success btn-xs" %>
```

Now, lets admit I'd like to allow a manager of the site to select both a start_date and an end_date so these parameters are passed to controller#method in order to generate a report for this date-range. I tried the following but I have no clue how to pass those (start_date/end_date) variables to the controller. Here is non-working code (see CAPS in button_to params):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="start date" id="start_date" class='datepicker'>
<input type="text" placeholder="end date" id="end_date" class='datepicker'>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#start_date').datepicker();
    $('#end_date').datepicker();
    START_PLZ = $('#start_date').datepicker().val();
    END_PLZ = $('#end_date').datepicker().val();
  });
</script>

<%= button_to t('.download_pdf', :default => "Download PDF BTC Statement"), download_pdf_admin_user_path(@user), 
                                 :action  => :download_pdf, 
                                 :params  => { start_date: START_PLZ, end_date: END_PLZ },
                                 :class   => "btn btn-success btn-xs" %>
```

Is there any way I can use those JS variables and pass them to my generate_pdf methods when I press the button? Otherwise I might use a form. 
Any input apreciated.

Comment: i think you have to add proper action with `remote:true` option inside `button_to`  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Answer (score 1):

Erb is server side templating engine so the code is executed on server side where as the JS code is on client side, so unfortunately there is no direct way.
**But**
What we can do is create another form for dates with remote option set to true (RAILS AJAX FORM), so once its submitted we can load button_to into view and now we will be having values in params. Should work I guess.